# React Router V4: How to render a modal in the same screen changing only the url and then with that url, be able to rebuild the whole screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to build a modal that behaves similar to the modal that it's used to display a specific tweet.

[image]

1. In that screenshot you can see that whenever the modal is open, a status code is appended to the original url, but I remain in the same screen.
2. Then if a take that url and paste it into the browser's address bar I
   get the same content loaded in the background with the modal open
   just as it was when I copied the url.

[The react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery) has got me covered with the first part, that is, loading a modal in the same screen.

Here's the react-router example in codesandbox

[image: Edit Modal Gallery-clone]

The problem is that I have no idea what to do to make it possible for a user to bookmark the url that it's created when the modal is display (in the example **/gallery/img/1**)

[image]
and then based on that url being able to load the page with the same component(the Gallery component) in the background and the modal open.

P.S. In the example in codesandbox, I intentionally left out some routes in the ModalSwitch component.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could create two routes, gallery and gallery/img/:id, that point to the same gallery component.  Then during componentWillMount of the gallery component you could check if the URL contains an id param and decide to render the modal and which image to load.

You could then bookmark the UR, possibly remove for the ModalSwitch component entirely and also allow for redirecting a user back to the gallery route when closing the modal, keeping the URL accurate at all times.

Comment: Sorry for not replying before. I tried what you suggested. Here's a link to the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rlr967yr1q). I kinda works, because it  allows for the url to be bookmarked, but since the same url `gallery/img/:id` is repeated twice, I also need to press the browser's back button twice in order to get redirected to the tab's default page.

Comment: If you wanna try out the example, try downloading the code first, as the bug I mentioned in the previous comment for some reason does not appear when the app is run directly from the sandbox.